# Как в Mongo обновить документ без удаления остальных полей?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Есть схема:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
field: {},
field2: {},
field3: {
    innerField1: String,
    innerField2: String,
    innerField3: String,
    innerField4: String,
    innerField5: String,
    innerField6: String
}
});
```

Представим что схема полностью заполнена и мне нужно обновить некоторые данные

Пример запроса:
(Я не знаю какие поля в field3 мне прийдут, все время могут быть абсолютно разные)

```
{
   field3: {
      innerField2: String,
      innerField4: String
   }
}
```

Как мне обновить выборочные поля в "Field3" и при этом не удалить остальные?

```
 Schema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {$set: req.body.field3}, function(err, res) {});
```

Не работает, удаляет остальные поля :(

Жду ваших ответов, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema.UpdateById(userId, {$set:{"field3": req.body.field3}}, function(err, res) {});
```